# Extending Actions On Google AOG Dialogflow Entities to Tackle non US/UK English locale input

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Hope all is well during these challenging times!

I would like to put it out there with regards to the best practice on Extending Dialogflow Entities and tackling non US/UK english locale input.

My challenge was to get accurate location values for Suburbs and Cities (parameters) in Australia. My team has tested many different ways of doing so with just using the standard system entities but non was able to capture the above accurately. It seems most of the location based entity types are geared towards US and UK but not AU (and perhaps other countries non US/UK).

The team had to implement a custom entity that has the list of suburbs and cities for australia. A roadblock that we came across shows that you can only grab 10,000 max entities (else Dialogflow and AoG won't sync/update). Our procured list has more than that for suburbs and hence we have to do a fair bit of work trimming it down which we did.

Question is, are we doing it the right way -> custom entity with csv list imported? For instance should we use the training path instead and stick to Sys.Geo-City and Sys.location?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if your set of suburbs and cities can be organized in this way, uploading a CSV would provide better accuracy for your use case. If you are over 10K values for a given entity type, you can split it into several entities and allow an intent to match either entity.